# Convert SqlServer Query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have written the below given query in SQL server 2008:

```
(SELECT p.postid, 
         p.title, 
        p.disabled, 
        l.locationname 
  FROM   posts p 
        INNER JOIN categories c 
                 ON p.categoryid = c.categoryid 
        INNER JOIN users u 
                 ON p.userid = u.userid 
        INNER JOIN tags t 
                 ON p.tagid = t.tagid 
        INNER JOIN locations l 
                 ON p.locationid = l.locationid 
        LEFT JOIN postimages pm 
                ON p.postid = pm.postid 
 WHERE  p.categoryid = 1 
  GROUP  BY p.postid, 
            p.title, 
            p.disabled, 
            l.locationname) 
ORDER  BY p.postid DESC
```

I want to write the above query in LINQ.

I tried a little and able to write the query below:

```
var objPosts = (from p in _dbcontext.Posts
                        join us in _dbcontext.Users on p.UserId equals us.UserId
                        join tag in _dbcontext.Tags on p.TagId equals tag.TagId
                        join cat in _dbcontext.Categories on p.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
                        join loc in _dbcontext.Locations on p.LocationId equals loc.LocationId
                        join img in _dbcontext.PostImages on p.PostId equals img.PostId into gj
                        from postimg in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        where p.Disabled == false && p.CategoryId == userPost.CategoryId || p.UserId == userPost.UserId || p.TagId == userPost.TagId || p.LocationId == userPost.LocationId

                        orderby p.PostId descending

                        select new
                        {
                            PostId = p.PostId,
                            PostTitle = p.Title,
                            //ImageInfo = postimg.ImagePath,
                            //ThumbNailInfo = p.ThubNailInfo,
                            PostShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
                            UserId = us.UserId,
                            UserName = us.Name,
                            TagId = tag.TagId,
                            TagTitle = tag.Title,
                            CategoryId = cat.CategoryId,
                            CategoryName = cat.CategoryName,
                            LocationId = loc.LocationId,
                            LocationName = loc.LocationName
                        });
```

I am unable to apply the group by logic in LINQ. Can anyone please convert my SQL to LINQ. Thanks

Comment: have u tried with group by in linq? if yes what error its giving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 group new { p, l } by new
          {
            p.postid, 
            p.title, 
            p.disabled, 
            l.locationname
           } into g
  orderby g.Key.PostId descending 

 select new
          {
           g.key.postid, 
           g.key.title, 
           g.key.disabled, 
           g.key.locationname

           }
```

Comment: I used the above logic and got the given error:  

LINQPad.User.Posts' does not contain a definition for 'postid' and no extension method 'postid' accepting a first argument of type 'LINQPad.User.Posts' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: I just want to know the syntax of using group by on multiple tables, rest I will do myself. So if are you able to make the above SQL query in LINQ, can you please update your answer in the more precise way.

Comment: Finally I get my result. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

The missing part in your query is that you are not selecting anything...

You got the joins ok, left outer join ok, predicates (where), ordering, but no projection, and no group by.

Below should get you started:

```
group p by p.PostId into pg
select new {Post=p, Location=loc};
```

This would return return a collection of new objects whose properties Post and Location.